# How do I select kendo grid items by Id passed in by an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid with `checkbox` selection in my MVC web application.  I am trying to set some initial selections that trigger on `databind`.  Here is my grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel>()
.Name("MyGrid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Select().Width(50);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Name")
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onChange"))
.PersistSelection()    
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Test"))
))
```

You'll notice that under the `events` parameter I've set a function to trigger on `DataBound` called `onChange`.  This function is where I want to make my initial selections.  I started writing a function to achieve this and Telerik assisted with some code:

```
function onChange(e) {
    //Sample array
    var arr = [206, 210];

    for (var i = 0; i < e.sender.items().length; i++) {
        //206 is a test value, I want to pass an array in.
        if (e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.items()[i]).Id == 206) {
            e.sender.select(e.sender.items()[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code only takes me part of the way.  What I want to do and where I need help is, adjusting this code to accept an array of Ids and select those items.  For testing purposes, I have made a very basic array called `arr` but I'm not sure how to pass this into the loop.

I attempted to get it working using a jquery `each` loop to iterate over every value in the array and select the row but it didn't work.  The code was something like:

```
function onChange(e) {
    //Sample array
    var arr = [206, 210];

    $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
        if (e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.items()[i]).Id == v) {
            e.sender.select(e.sender.items()[i]);
        }
    })
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you exaactly want to do with thoes array ids?

Comment: As I stated above in my question, these Id's are what will be used to select the items in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if each `Id` exists in the array:

```
function onChange(e) {
    //Sample array
    var arr = [206, 210],
        grid = e.sender;

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.items().length; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(grid.dataItem(grid.items()[i]).Id) > -1) {
            grid.select(grid.items()[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Working example:

```js
let arr = [1,3,5,7],
    data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    
for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (arr.indexOf(data[i]) > -1) {
    console.log(`item ${data[i]} exists in the array`);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much @dontvotemedown

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a namespaced myApp with functions where I added a `klookup` function to return the first match in an array, then select using that.  Note I used the `dataBound` event using a kendo data sample.

```js
// create a namespace for my functions
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.funcs = {
  klookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.items().length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray.dataItem(myArray.items()[i])[property] == searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray.items()[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  onDataBound: function(e) {
    // console.log("onDataBound");
    myApp.data.Sender = e.sender;
    let s = myApp.data.Sender
    // console.dir(myApp.data.arr);
    let rows = s.items();
    //console.log(rows);
    myApp.data.arr.forEach(function(entry) {
      let found = myApp.funcs.klookup(s, entry, "OrderID", true);
      s.select(found[0]);
    });
  }
};
// add data to my namespace
myApp.data = {
  arr: [10248, 10250]
};
$(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            OrderID: {
              type: "number"
            },
            Freight: {
              type: "number"
            },
            ShipName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            OrderDate: {
              type: "date"
            },
            ShipCity: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 5,
      serverPaging: true,
      serverFiltering: true,
      serverSorting: true
    },
    persistSelection: true,
    dataBound: myApp.funcs.onDataBound,
    height: 550,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        selectable: true,
        width: "50px"
      }, {
        field: "OrderID",
        filterable: false
      },
      "Freight",
      {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      }, {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      }, {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```